# How do I download a Django webpage into a PDF with all the css when user clicks "PDF" button? (Exactly how it looks, into a PDF)

Tags: python, html, css, django, pdf

I have tried using multiple technologies like weasyprint and reportlab but have not been able to make the webpage that the user is seeing into a pdf. I have read the documentation but maybe I am missing steps but I eventually want to take the exact page they are looking at and when the press the "PDF" button, it downloads the entire web page into a PDF with all the css and everything.

The webpage does contain heatmap charts made with plotly, at times the webpage can have 2 charts or sometimes up to 20 charts.

I currently just call the 'window.print()' function but it cuts off the charts and I was hoping that if I utilize weasyprint or a similar technology then I can have the charts be displayed correctly.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `window.print()` and to avoid your charts being cut in the middle of a page, you can add a CSS class (e.g. widget) to them and add to your CSS:

```
@media print {
  .widget {
    break-inside: avoid;
    page-break-inside: avoid;
  }
}
```

Comment: the graphs are inside a bootstraps row -> column and when I add this as well as margins on each side, it only affects the page and not the charts. The charts are still being cut  and not displaying fully while the entire page is the one being affected by the css. Would this be the best way to pursue the solution instead of weasyprint or reportlab?

Comment: well, I use this technique extensively with chartjs charts, the thing is you have to be very careful with what kind of html structure you use, since the kind of CSS markup I showed you does not work very well with modern, flexible layouts like grid. Other than that this solution works like a charm, and avoids code duplication. If not, yes, you can author a pdf from scratch (e.g. reportlab) but it will be much more complex IMHO

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate all the help, I have been struggling with reportlab and weasyprint since it is definitely much more complex. I think I might head down the path you are suggesting. I will just need to make sure the html structure and hierarchy all coordinate well then to apply these changes. Thanks

Comment: no problem! Yes it takes a bit of time to set up but then it just works! Also, if you need running headers and footers, it took me a long time to figure out but I have something that works, so I could share a bit of code if needed.

Comment: I appreciate all the help, I ended up using reportlab. I did give it a shot with your method but was going to have to move around a lot of code. If I would have started out with your method it would have been best. With reportlab i stored the graphs i needed as PNGs then used reportlab's drawImage() function to display them. A different solution than I initially was searching for but it worked. Thanks

Comment: no problem! Glad to be able to help, maybe on a future project you'll give it a go!